# Angularjs method not find wile executing grunt command

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Am working on a angular js project .Trying to write a test case for a method inside my app.js
There are two types of method my js file

1.

```
$scope.myfunction =function(){
}
```

2. 

```
function myfunction(){
}
```

I had write few test cases for fist types of method and its working fine. Now i have write a test case for  second types of method and its getting failed. Code changes are given below

### app.js

```
function readCookie(name) {
        var names = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(names) == 0) return c.substring(names.length,c.length);
            }
        return null;
        }
```

**app-spe.js**

```
describe('readCookie', function() {
                     beforeEach(inject(function() {
                        spyOn(document,'token').andReturn('aaaaa.bbbbb.ccccc');
                     }));                    
                     it('should get readCookie', function() {   
             
                        expect(readCookie('token')).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
                     });
    });
```

When i run the **grunt** command getting the below error

[image]

Any one have any idea for writing test cases for these kind of method. Expecting valid response

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try 1. export the function and import it in the spec. 2. Also convert the function to more functional - make its implicit dependencies like document expilict - meaning put document as a parameter to the function. That way if would be easier to mock document as plain object.

Comment: am not fully understand what u said. Can u please give any example